# how to Display message when two different user access the same post to edit in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I Want to display a warning message in my plugin when the two user opens a same post to edit using wordpress Please help

Thank you

Comment: What you tried so far buddy? And where is your plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Add new column to posts - `locked_by` and `locked_until` - first one having user ID, who is currently making any changes and second one holding time, for how long this post will be locked/marked as being currently edited.

For example:
When user A enters into edit mode, check if current post

`locked_until > now() && locked_by != currentUser` (pseudocode).

If yes, then display warning.

If `locked_by == currentUser`,

then extend `locked_until` for, say, next 5 minutes.